# Repeatedly corrupted snapshots on vmware workstation

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I have recently started using a Windows 7 virtual machine for development running on VMware Workstation 12.1.1 Pro. To keep a bit of control on some risky changes, I keep a snapshot that I delete every few days and immediately create a new one. Snapshots are always taken with the vm off.

My problem is that I have had the snapshot files corrupted multiple times now. 
The error I get reads:

> The operation on file "C:\VMs\machine\Machine-000001-s009.vmdk"
>   failed.
>
> [Error image Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsjP7.png)

I get the options to Retry, Continue or Cancel. Retry and continue don't help and Cancel kills the vm.

Interestingly the corruption has always been on snapshot files but never on the main disk.

The last corruption happened after I deleted the snapshot (which successfully integrated the data into the main virtual disk) and created a new snapshot. I then took a full backup on my system and then launched the vm again. I got the corrupted disk error above. I then proceeded to delete all the snapshot files and replace them with the snapshot files from the backup. The vm booted fine after that.

Initially I thought that maybe Acronis, my backup software, was interfering with a running vm so I made sure the vm was off when the backup took place. But this theory is thrown out the windows as the corruption took place again.

I checked my Samsung 850 PRO SSD's SMART data and I have 0 reallocated sectors nor anything else alarming.

Has anybody experienced this kind of corruption? Any ideas on what to test on my system to stop this from occurring again? Is my SSD failing? How could I test my SSD properly?

Comment: "Has anybody experienced this kind of corruption?" - Numerous times and I also use Acronis.  I have no solution to the problem.

Comment: @Ramhound Does your corruption take place only on snapshots or have you also experienced it on the main vmdk files? I think Acronis uses it's own version of VSS (Volume shadow copy) and I wonder if that is the culprit? Or are we chasing a red herring?

Comment: I experienced corruption on every single one of my main .vmdk files.  I would restore the files and it would happen again.  The current version by default uses their own version of VSS by default.  The default can be changed.

Comment: I've had snapshot corruption on occasion and I swear it's McAfee antivirus - that my employer insist on using.

Comment: Found that the latest versions of vmware have this version fixed

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, my solution was to revert back to VMware 11.4 (last release).

I was able to produce the problem in a repeatable fashion on 12.x, but version 11.4 has been testing OK for the past 10 hours.

This problem has killed about 24 man-hours of productivity for me.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I am pretty sure I experienced the same problem with version 11.